# How to update the user-defined variable value based on the parameter value in yaml file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, ado, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using below yaml file to build pipeline. It is defined with 2 variables.

```
parameters:
  - name: tag 
    type: string
    default: '@Test1'

  - name: forkCount
    type: number
    default: 0

variables:
  - name: ENV
    value: QA

  - name: fork_opt
    value: ''
    
    ${{ if gt(parameters.forkCount, 0) }}:
      fork_opt: '-DforkCount=${{ parameters.forkCount }} -Dhub=https://huburl.com' --> Getting error here
    ${{ else }}:
      fork_opt: '
      
stages:
  #stages to be follow. task uses fork_opt
```

I have a user-defined variable (ENV) which is static. I defined another variable (fork_opt) - whose value should be assigned at run time based on the 'forkCount' parameter value

When I run a pipeline, getting  below error

```
/azure-pipelines-generic.yml (Line: 18, Col: 7): Unexpected value 'fork_opt'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it through below syntax

```
  variables:
    - name: ENV
      value: QA

    - ${{ if gt(parameters.forkCount, 0) }}:
      - name: fork_opt
        value: '-DforkCount=${{ parameters.forkCount }} -Dhub=https://huburl.com'
    - ${{ else }}:
      - name: fork_opt
        value: ''
```

Comment: so what was the issue ? missing quotes / typo?

Comment: @Thomas I was declaring a variable initially and then trying to override it with conditional statement which is not allowed under that space

False Syntax I used:

- name: fork_opt
    value: ''
    
    ${{ if gt(parameters.forkCount, 0) }}:
      fork_opt: '-DforkCount=${{ parameters.forkCount }} -Dhub=https://huburl.com' 
    ${{ else }}:
      fork_opt: '

Corrected Syntax:
- ${{ if gt(parameters.forkCount, 0) }}:
      - name: fork_opt
        value: '-DforkCount=${{ parameters.forkCount }} -Dhub=https://huburl.com'
- ${{ else }}:
      - name: fork_opt
        value: ''